# Flag using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (UPDATE( HighestDegreeDoc) OR UPDATE (GPA) OR UPDATE (CreditHours))     
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[School]
        SET Uploaded = 1
        FROM dbo.School
        JOIN INSERTED i ON i.EmpID = dbo.School.RecID
        END
    RETURN         
END

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TrigEdu]
ON [dbo].[Education]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT (UPDATE( HighestDegreeDoc) OR UPDATE (GPA) OR UPDATE (CreditHours))     
    RETURN

    UPDATE [dbo].[School]
    SET Uploaded = 1
    FROM dbo.School
    JOIN INSERTED i ON i.EmpID = dbo.School.RecID
END
```

These both codes are giving me same result. I want only when these three fields 
change one of them then `School.RecID` update. But its update dating with any updates made in any field of Education Table. :(

Comment: Just let me try to recap: you want the trigger to perform its job only when these three columns are updated (all or some of them). But the trigger seems to be working when any column in `Education` is updated, not necessarily one of these three. Is that right? If so, please elaborate more on how you update the `Education` table. I mean, do you use a stored procedure to update all the data or do you issue UPDATE statements to update columns individually?

Comment: yes you got it right, but i am adding some thing more into it. my orginal columns places are 2,3,10,16 . if i use (UPDATE) only 2 ,3 works but not others. should i use something else than UPDATE. i using OR with UPDATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a trigger off an update you can access both the new and the old version of the record. You've got Inserted, the new version, you just need to compare it to Deleted, the old version.

```
UPDATE dbo.School
SET Uploaded = 1
FROM dbo.School
JOIN INSERTED i ON i.EmpID = dbo.School.RecID
JOIN DELETED d ON d.EmpID = dbo.School.RecID
where i.HighestDegreeDoc != d.HighestDegreeDoc
or i.GPA != d.GPA
or i.CreditHours != d.CreditHours
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't refer to columns by number in SQL.

Comment: This code goes in the update trigger, but it only updates Uploaded to 1 if there is a change in one of the three columns (by name). Inserted (i) represents the new version of the row, Deleted (d) represents the old version of the row. if one of those three are different, it does the update.